# Problem calling a Node.js v10.15.3 project

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, gulp

I am loading a project with Node v10.15.3 version.
Everything loads correctly when I call it:

```
user@host:~/node-proyect/primo-explore-devenv/primo-explore/custom$ gulp run --view 49HFMN_V2 --ve
[13:53:40] Working directory changed to ~/node-proyect/primo-explore-devenv
[13:53:41] Using gulpfile ~/node-proyect/primo-explore-devenv/gulpfile.js
[13:53:41] Starting 'run'...
[13:53:41] Starting 'select-view'...
[13:53:41] Finished 'select-view' after 4.43 ms
[13:53:41] Starting 'connect:primo_explore'...
[13:53:41] Starting 'select-view'...
[13:53:41] Finished 'select-view' after 445 μs
[13:53:41] Starting '<anonymous>'...
[13:53:42] Finished '<anonymous>' after 78 ms
[13:53:42] Finished 'connect:primo_explore' after 79 ms
[13:53:42] Starting 'reinstall-primo-node-modules'...
[13:53:42] Starting 'select-view'...
[13:53:42] Finished 'select-view' after 481 μs
[13:53:42] Starting '<anonymous>'...
[13:53:42] Finished '<anonymous>' after 226 μs
[13:53:42] Finished 'reinstall-primo-node-modules' after 1.57 ms
[13:53:42] Starting 'setup_watchers'...
[13:53:42] Starting 'select-view'...
[13:53:42] Finished 'select-view' after 330 μs
[13:53:42] Starting 'watch-js'...
[13:53:42] Starting 'select-view'...
[13:53:42] Finished 'select-view' after 310 μs
[13:53:42] Starting '<anonymous>'...
[13:53:42] Finished '<anonymous>' after 10 ms
[13:53:42] Finished 'watch-js' after 11 ms
[13:53:42] Starting 'watch-custom-scss'...
[13:53:42] Starting 'select-view'...
[13:53:42] Finished 'select-view' after 402 μs
[13:53:42] Starting '<anonymous>'...
[13:53:42] Finished '<anonymous>' after 172 μs
[13:53:42] Finished 'watch-custom-scss' after 898 μs
[13:53:42] Starting 'watch-css'...
[13:53:42] Starting 'select-view'...
[13:53:42] Finished 'select-view' after 267 μs
[13:53:42] Starting '<anonymous>'...
[13:53:42] Finished '<anonymous>' after 2.68 ms
[13:53:42] Finished 'watch-css' after 3.26 ms
[13:53:42] Starting '<anonymous>'...
[13:53:42] Finished '<anonymous>' after 471 μs
[13:53:42] Finished 'setup_watchers' after 16 ms
[13:53:42] Starting 'custom-js'...
[13:53:42] Starting 'select-view'...
[13:53:42] Finished 'select-view' after 286 μs
[13:53:42] Starting 'custom-html-templates'...
[13:53:42] Starting 'select-view'...
[13:53:42] Finished 'select-view' after 248 μs
[13:53:42] Starting '<anonymous>'...
[13:53:42] Finished '<anonymous>' after 14 ms
[13:53:42] Finished 'custom-html-templates' after 14 ms
[13:53:42] Starting '<anonymous>'...
[13:53:42] Finished '<anonymous>' after 8.21 ms
[13:53:42] Finished 'custom-js' after 23 ms
[13:53:42] Starting 'custom-scss'...
[13:53:42] Starting 'select-view'...
[13:53:42] Finished 'select-view' after 511 μs
[13:53:42] Starting '<anonymous>'...
[13:53:42] Finished '<anonymous>' after 190 μs
[13:53:42] Finished 'custom-scss' after 1.18 ms
[13:53:42] Starting 'custom-css'...
[13:53:42] Starting 'select-view'...
[13:53:42] Finished 'select-view' after 254 μs
[13:53:42] Starting '<anonymous>'...
[13:53:42] Finished '<anonymous>' after 7.91 ms
[13:53:42] Finished 'custom-css' after 8.51 ms
[13:53:42] Finished 'run' after 136 ms
[Browsersync] Access URLs:
 ----------------------------------
       Local: http://localhost:8003
    External: http://127.0.0.1:8003
 ----------------------------------
          UI: http://localhost:3001
 UI External: http://localhost:3001
 ----------------------------------
[Browsersync] Serving files from: primo-explore
```

Just at that point it stays waiting for the browser call, but when I call the web from the browser:

```
http://host_URL:8003/discovery/?vid=49HFMN:49HFMN_V2
```

throws the following error:

```
...
[Browsersync] Serving files from: primo-explore
custom/49HFMN_V2
undefined:1


SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/user/node-proyect/primo-explore-devenv/gulp/tasks/08-servers.js:59:53)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:194:15)
    at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:459:23)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1125:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
```

and execution is stopped.

In this link you can find the project that I am trying to implement in Node.js with the package.json in root:

https://github.com/ExLibrisGroup/primo-explore-devenv

How can I solve it? Any ideas?

Thank you very much.

P.S. I don't have much experience with running Node JS, any recommendations for a free course or tutorial to learn how to use it and solve bugs?

Comment: Seems to me, like it's fetch from the wrong folder, you run the app in one folder, it changes and then it tries to fetch from a folder it can't find, check your relative addresses and manage current execution path better.

Comment: Can you add package json file, you can check this guy tutorial for javascript.https://youtube.com/c/TraversyMedia

Comment: @Anuga How can I check these relative addresses?

Comment: @AnserAli here is the complete project, there you can see the package.json in root. 
https://github.com/ExLibrisGroup/primo-explore-devenv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by uninstalling all node.js and reinstalling everything with NVM version control, which I didn't know before and allows me to have everything more controlled and allows me to solve more easily problems with the installation.

In short, something unsolvable was wrong with the Node.js system and as there was no remedy I had to take the radical path.

Answer (score -1):

@Naschkopf you don't have any files under the folder primo-explore/custom please check the point 9 of the installation guide. In your command

```
 gulp run --view 49HFMN_V2
```

I am unable to find the 49HFMN_V2 in repo it has to be under primo-explore/custom

> Populate your custom View package folder in the custom package folder ("...primo-explore\custom"), by either downloading the view code files from your Primo Back Office or using the primo-explore-package GitHub repository) to start a new package folder. (if you have already defined a view package and loaded it to the BO - make sure you download it or else you will not see, and may overwrite, your previous changes.)

Comment: The project is in the folder, that is not the problem.

user@host:/home/user/node-proyect/primo-explore-devenv/primo-explore/custom# ls

|| 49HFMN_V2  primo-explore-package